# how can i snip transaction from metamask?

Tags: web3js, bsc, defi

on buying from any Defi website they ask to connect using your wallet and confirm transaction when buying, now I want to build python code that can snip transacation from the metamask and submit the transaction using my private code without the need of the confirmation process and the pop-up window any suggestion on how to do that?
ps: i want to do this in BSC

Comment: Very Bad Idea! Your technically asking for a private KEY. If you want to create a wallet you should look into how to create a wallet. Your question is using the term snip?

Comment: @MadeInDreams i want the transaction info (adresse, qty) rather than applying it to metamask i would like the transaction to use my wallet rather thn metamask

Comment: @Yahya-_ Can you edit the question and clarify what are you trying to achieve? Do you want to write a Metamask replacement in python?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your asking this kind of question shows that you don't have the knowledge to perform such task at this moment. However, if you want to build a wallet as a standalone app that you sign so it does not get flag by AV and ppl know it's from you that is more accessible.

What your asking is possible. I can connect metamask to my own provider. Set a custum RPC url that will handle the transaction and use it on my own chain that is not even EVM based.

I can also create an electron app, pack it as executable and sign it. This is the best solution in my opinion to distribute an app.

Maybe have a look at the requirement to be listed in the extension page for chrome and the app store.

But your not there yet. I suggest you look into what is it exactly your trying to achieve. I would also be interested on learning more about that snip procedure. Is this an algorithm you built?

Rest assure that there are a lot a security steps you will have to go trough before you can use that eth_snip method.